# Escribir etiquetas HTML en un archivo JSON

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, idioma

Mi problema es este.
Tengo un archivo JSON con textos que quiero que varíen en el HTML. No sé si me explico, es para cambiar de un idioma a otro.

El problema es que tengo etiquetas HTML en esos textos y el navegador me escribe las etiquetas.

```json
{
    "es":{
    "text" : "Quiero que este texto tenga una palabra en <i>cursiva</i> y otra en <b>bold</b>"
    },
    
    "en:{
    "text : "I want this text to have one word in <i> italic </i> and another in <b> bold </b>"
    }
}
```

El recorrido que hace por JavaScript es:

```javascript
$.getJSON("lang.json", function(json)
{
    //Lenguaje por defecto de la página sessionStorage.setItem("lang", "idioma")"
    if(!localStorage.getItem("lang"))
    {
        localStorage.setItem("lang", "en");
    }
    let lang = localStorage.getItem("lang");
    let doc = json;

    $('.lang').each(function()
    {
        $(this).text(doc[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
    });//Each

    $('.flagLgs').click(function()
    {
        localStorage.setItem("lang", $(this).attr('id')) ;
        let lang = $(this).attr('id');
        let doc = json;

        $('.lang').each(function()
        {
            $(this).text(doc[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
        });     //Each
    });     //Funcion click
});     //Get json AJAX
```

Y lo muestro en HTML así:

```html
<p class="lang" key="text"></p>
```

Pero el navegador me escribe tal cual, con todo y etiquetas. ¿Qué puede ser lo que falla?, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que se ejecuten las etiquetas HTML como debe ser?

Muchas gracias a todos por vuestro tiempo,

Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La función `text()` inserta un **string** en crudo dentro del elemento del selector, en cambio la función `html()` inserta contenido susceptible de ser interpretado por el navegador como **HTML**.

```js
const miTexto = 'Esto es mi texto <strong>con etiquetas HTML</strong>';

$(function() {
  $('#text').text(miTexto);
  $('#html').html(miTexto);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="text"></div>
<div id="html"></div>
```

En tu caso, al usar la función `text()` estás insertando en el **DOM** un **string** literal, por eso no se están interpretando las etiquetas **HTML**. Si usas la función `html()` deberías ver resuelto tu problema.

**Referencias:** [text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/), [html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Efectivamente fue la solución al problema.